# Process vector elements in separate threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm trying to process elements of a vector in separate threads and put the results in a different vector. I've tried with mutexes and with critical sections around the code where I check and take out elements from the input vector, but I'm getting access violations when I run the code.

Edit: I've updated the code to put the results back in the vector in a different critical section and also initialize the vector before the threads start.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define MAX_THREADS  4

void InvertProc( void * MyID );      // Threads 2 to n: display 
void ShutDown( void );               // Program shutdown 

int     ThreadNr;                    // Number of threads started 
CRITICAL_SECTION cs, cs2;

std::vector<int> _oTempVector;
std::vector<int> _oOutVector;

int OutCounter;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{     
   ThreadNr = 0;
   OutCounter = 0;

   for ( int i = 0; i < 50000; i++ ) {
      _oTempVector.push_back( i );
      _oOutVector.push_back( 0 );
   }

   InitializeCriticalSection( &cs );   
   InitializeCriticalSection( &cs2 ); 

   std::vector<HANDLE> events;
   for ( ThreadNr = 0; ThreadNr < MAX_THREADS; ThreadNr++ ) {            
      HANDLE handle = (HANDLE)_beginthread( InvertProc, 0, &ThreadNr );      
      events.push_back( handle );
   }

   WaitForMultipleObjects( events.size(), &events[0], true, INFINITE );  

   std::cout << "outvector contains:" << _oOutVector.size() << "elements"; 
   std::cout << '\n'; 
}


void InvertProc( void *pMyID )
{   
   do {
      EnterCriticalSection( &cs ); 
      if ( _oTempVector.size() > 0 ) {
         int iElement = _oTempVector.back();
         _oTempVector.pop_back();
         LeaveCriticalSection( &cs );

         iElement *= -1;

         EnterCriticalSection( &cs2 ); 
         _oOutVector[OutCounter] = iElement; 
         OutCounter++;
         LeaveCriticalSection( &cs2 );
      }
   } while ( _oTempVector.size() > 0 );   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your output vector isn't inside the critical section as a shared object it should.... 
because if several thread try to push_back at the same time, you face a Write over Write Data race!!!!

```
  EnterCriticalSection( &cs ); 
  if ( _oTempVector.size() > 0 ) {
     int iElement = _oTempVector.back();
     _oTempVector.pop_back();
          iElement *= -1;
     _oOutVector.push_back( iElement );   
     LeaveCriticalSection( &cs );
  }
 } while ( _oTempVector.size() > 0 );
```

the resulting running thread will run more sequentially than concurrently

to solve that, you must thing differently:
1) can you split the problem, each thread should work on consecutive element of the input vector
2) if the output vector was initialize at the beginning with the size of the input, you remove all the problem due to push!

each running thread will *-1 a given range of number the input an put the result at a specific place of the output vector (without interaction) with the other thread so you can remove lock

```
void InvertProc( void *pMyID )
{   
    int threadnum = *((int*)pMyID);
    int chunk = input.size()/THREAD_NUM;
    int start = threadnum*chunk;
    int end = start+chunk;
    for (I = start ; I < end ; ++I)
    {
        output[i] = input[i]*-1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: If I put it in the same critical section the resulting program will be not really parallel, just multithreaded, but it will run sequential. Of course in this case the processing of the elements (multiplying with -1) is a simple action, but in real life a time consuming operation is performed on the elements. I've tried putting the pushing of the elements in the outside vector in a different critical section (cs2), but it still didn't work.

Comment: Completely Agree with you, but the question was "why am I getting access violation" ... For the concurrency issue see some update in my answer!!!

Comment: I've updated the code with another critical section and without push_back, but now for 4 threads it results in a dead-lock.

Comment: and for your deadlock it can come from the critical section cs1, because you enter in cs1 before the if statement and never leaving cs1 if the condition isn't true!

Comment: Right, thank you, didn't see that coming! So should I enter the critical section after the if or put a leave also on the else case? I wanted the if to be in the critical section because otherwise another thread could consume all the elements of the vector which would result in fail on the back/pop_back!

Comment: yes it should work. isn't what I will do because you continue to lock and at the end I suspect that your 4 thread version will be slower than a sequential code!